# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, servidor, localhost

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web en CodeIgniter, es la primera vez que trabajo con ello, después de haber desarrollado la aplicación en mi **localhost**, decidí subirla a un server de pruebas, así que cargué mi sitio en él, posteriormente cambié las configuraciones en los archivos config.php y database.php. Pero ahora tengo un tremendo error, ya que me carga algunas páginas y otra no (en la que no me carga me aparece el error, 404 Page Not Found - The page you requested was not found.), no sé que esté pasando.

Comment: Ese error se debe porque en tu aplicación web no encuentra la ruta del archivo que haces petición, asegúrate que tengan la ruta adecuada.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estuve buscando en Internet que tal error también suele ocurrir por el nombre de los archivos, es decir la distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, también afecta. Ya pude solucionar tal problema.

Comment: Asegúrate que tanto como la ruta de los archivos y los nombres de tu proyecto estén correctos.
Por ejemplo, si el archivo se llama procesamiento.php y lo llamas desde un menu así: Procesamiento.php, el navegador te dará el error 404.

Comment: Seria ideal que dentro de la pregunta dejes la solución que te ayudó, recuerda que hay gente que puede llegar aquí buscando la solución al mismo problema.

Comment: Recuerda también usar bien las rutas relativas y absolutas, ya que aveces te puedes perder en la pagina y cometer un error al moverte en tu sitio.